# RegEx for a string of length 0-2

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match a string that can be either empty or have 1 or 2 numbers in it such as the following:

"" (empty)
"1"
"23"

String with more numbers or non-numeric characters should not match.  My closest guess is the regex:

[0-9]{0,2}

Which I read to say "the numbers 0 through 9 occurring 0 to 2 times."  However, in practice I find that regex also matches longer strings like "333".  How is it possible to restrict string length in regular expressions?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Use the following regex:

```
^[0-9]{0,2}$
```

You almost had it -- the `^` and `$` characters are **anchors** that match the beginning and end of the string, respectively.

For a more in-depth discussion on anchors, see [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html):

> [Anchors] do not match any character at all. Instead, they match a position before, after or between characters. They can be used to "anchor" the regex match at a certain position.

Comment: I've got false on test just for a space between `,` and second range number...

Answer (score 9):

You need to [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) the regex:

```
^[0-9]{0,2}$
```

Otherwise the regex will happily match substrings.

Answer (score 6):

Use the metacharacters for start and end of string:

```
^[0-9]{0,2}$
```

If you don't use them, it matches anywhere in the string, and "12", which matches, is part of "123".